# Trying to grab value from div with req.body

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

In express app I have button which incrementing value, and that value should be multiple with price. That value is in a div, not in a form.
In JS I would do something like this:

```
document.getElementById('quantity').innerHTML;
```

But how to grab this value with express?
I was thinking with help of hidden form element, has anyone suggestion or better solution?

```
<td data-th="Quantity" id="quantity" class="text-right">5</td>

<form action="#" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="quantityVal" value="{{ ?? }}">
</form>
```

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFnYQ.png)

Comment: a question... when you say express you are talking about server side express script ? If yes, you need to submit this request and use req.param method

Answer (score 0):

You can't just "grab" a value from HTML with Express. The only way is to perform an AJAX request and send that value with your request to your Node server, where you can access it with req.body.

You can read more about AJAX here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

Answer (score 0):

The server can only reach what's in the request, it can never reach the web page itself. If you have 2 different pages that send exactly the same request, the server will treat them the same.

So you yes, hidden input is the way to go.